# Using Sticky Text JQuery only on Desktop View

Tags: jquery, mobile, sticky

New to all things coding here - I found this code to have my text float alongside my images as you scroll and it worked just fine in desktop view but in mobile the text flows behind images.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sticky").sticky({topSpacing:10}); 
    $("#sticky").sticky({bottomSpacing:1450}); 
  });
</script>
```

So now I'm trying to figure out a way for this code only work on screens larger than 640px.
I found this:

```
if(window.outerWidth < 640) {
  alert('your jquery code here - it fires for mobile device only');
}
```

but when I put it together, and change it from less than 640 to greater than - the code doesn't work:

```
if(window.outerWidth > 640) {
  alert(  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sticky").sticky({topSpacing:10}); 
    $("#sticky").sticky({bottomSpacing:1450}); 
  });
);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help with a solution would be great appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide the error message from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code will initialize on page load, on resizing window nothing will happen since you are not listening that event and its already initialized after page load.

So you can listen to resize event and if condition matches initialize or simply unstick the element using [`unstick()`](https://github.com/garand/sticky#usage) method.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
 if(window.outerWidth > 640) {
    $("#sticky").sticky({topSpacing:10, bottomSpacing:1450}); 
 } else{
    // unstick the element
    $("#sticky").unstick()
 }
}).resize();
```

---

Or you can use css media queries to toggle between 2 elements.

```
#sticky { display:block; }
#stickyMob { display:none; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #sticky{ display: none;}
  #stickyMob { display:block; }
}
```

Comment: I still want the text to appear, I just don't want the "sticky" functionality in mobile

Comment: Thanks - for some reason unstick doesn't appear to be working. The text still flows behind images that are below it instead of pushing them down

Answer (score 0):

You dont require java script to do this. This can be easily done through **media queries**. You can also change your top and bottom spacing for mobile view(default will be applied for desktop) in your case.

Just like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { 
   //Your code
   #sticky{
      margin: 0; //or whatever
    }
}
```

This code will be embedded in your css linked with html file and will be automatically triggered when the scree will be minimized to 640 pixels.